# Upper Semi-Continuity in Metric Space

Tags: metric-spaces, continuity

Let $X$ be a metric space, and $f:X\rightarrow \mathbb R$.  Show these 
two properties are equivalent.

1. $\forall a\in \mathbb R$ the set $f^{-1} (-\infty,a)$ is open in $X$.
2. For any $x\in X$ and any sequence $\{x_n\}$ in $X$ with $x_n\to x$, $f(x)\geq \underset n\limsup f(x_n)$.

I'm really frustrated over this one. I tried many directions but failed, I guess I miss principle ideas. I said the following:

Assume $f^{-1} (-\infty,a)$ is open for all $a$'s. Let $(x_n)$ be a convergent sequence to some x, such that $f(x)=a$ for some real $a$. Then, $f^{-1} (-\infty,a)$ is open, so the complement is closed. Then, I can divide the sequence into 2 subsequences such that each of them is either entirely in $f^{-1} (-\infty,a)$, or entirely in the complement. for the "lower" subsequence it is easy to show that its $\limsup$ is less than or equal to $f(x)=b$, but I don't know what to make of the "upper" series. Thanks!

Comment: What's $x$ supposed to be?

Comment: You shouldn't take $a = f(x)$, you should pick an $a$ such that $f(x) < a$.